# What is the difference between Canvera and Karizma wedding albums?

Tags: printing, prints, wedding, canvas-prints, printed-album

What are the significant differences between Canvera and Karizma wedding albums?

Comment: @dpollitt That's an odd suggestion. I think the OP is asking this question to make use of the experience of others (who have used both albums), such that he can make an informed decision and *avoid* ordering both albums.

Comment: Maybe were interpreting the question differently, but as I see it Subhajit is not asking for an objective assessment of the print quality, he's just asking for the differences, so the *relative* qualities. Someone who has already ordered both the albums can easily provide an answer, e.g.: canvera has thicker paper than karizma (just an example, no clue if that's true)

Comment: I agree with Bart, I see the question as asking about relative qualities. Hopefully someone who has used both can offer the necessary comparison. If not, maybe Subhajit could follow dpollitt's suggestion, then return and answer his own question for the future benefit of others. ;)

Comment: Thing is, I think this is about two different brands/providers of photobooks, not two different types of albums: http://www.canvera.com; http://www.karizmaalbums.com  This may come under asking for a service recommendation.

Comment: I have no experience of any printed album.I just wanted to know  are there any difference between glossy or matte in printed quality or any size or aliment difference and which one is superior.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between wedding album print types?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/57163/whats-the-difference-between-wedding-album-print-types)

Comment: @Subhajit, it would be difficult to make a choice between vendors, some like one over the other, its hard to tell. But about glossy and matte, IMHO are personal taste. Matte prints try to give out rich contrast and are a good option when you do wedding prints. They don't reflect much, so you can see more details. Glossy look good too, but you can get visible fingerprints. Corporate pictures or a random party look good in glossy. HTH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        Canvera Album       Vs     Karizma Albums
```

The Quality Difference by means of print: I would rate them as 80% for Canvera and 90% for Karizma however when observed (as it should be) at a distance of 2ft from your face, there is very insignificant difference in them.

Paper Quality : 
I would definitely vote for the Karizma Album for paper quality since we get thicker sheets than that of Canvera.

Product Options :
There are lots of options in Canvera albums when compared to Karizma, however it may depend on the printer. 
Recently Canvera has been able to come up with a lot of options for paper types, non tearable, synthetic, and such. and types of covers.

I have been using and giving my clients canvera album only because of the customer relations. They get any faulty albums replaced within a week.

Karizma Works out if your budget is tighter, Canvera Works out if you want a hassle free work to be complete.

For Karizma u have to book individual add-ons for extra pay.
For Canvera U het a warranty card and Quality Assurance, A Jute bag which looks attractive, Proper Packing and delivery done at your door step. and most of all you have the option to share and view the virtual album online with authentications.

I hope this solves the question and gives you a clearer view of the products.